# Change Start type of Windows service in framework 4.5.1 c#

Tags: windows-services

I am currently using ManagementBaseObject to change the start type of a windows service . The logic seems to work fine in framework 2.0 wwebsite. The same logic doesnt seem to work in 4.5.1 framework. Has Microsoft turned  ManagementBaseObject obselete or is there any other approach to have it working in 4.5.1 website.

Thanks
Additional Info : ManagementBaseObject returns a value 2 in 4.5.1 and value 0 in 2. The difference in the 2 values is as follows,
0 --The request was accepted.
2 --The user did not have the necessary access.

However the access permission was the sameand is being pulled from the config

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with me not Impersonating the credentials in the 4.5.1  solution. It works without impersonation in place for the 2.0 version.